# Proxifying an application that doesn't implement that feature

Tags: windows, proxy, winsock

the problem is as follows:
I need to proxyify (sniff and **modify** packets) an appliaction that doesn't support proxy servers on Windows. The IP address it connects to is hard-coded in the application itself. I only need to modify the data, I don't care for the IP headers.

It would be a fairly simple task if not for the fact that I absolutely cannot modify the original appliaction or inject any code into it.

I need the original application to connect my program, and my program to the orignal server, so I think that simply rerouting the server's IP to localhost (as desribed [here](http://anime.myrpi.org/blog/2012/01/04/how-to-reroute-a-local-ip-address-to-localhost-127-0-0-1/)) won't work, because then my app can't connect to the orignal server.

Things like winpcap also are off-limits, as from what I've gathered there is no option to modify the packets as they go by.

If it's possible I would like to abstain from using a NDIS driver, as I need this setup to work across several versions of windows, and I don't have the means to write a driver for all of them.

I'm mostly coding in delphi, however I'm not afraid of c++, just to clarify why there isn't a language specified in the tags.

Any suggestion are welcome and I hope you have a nice day :)

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) project to do this.  Unlike WinPCAP, WinDivert *can* modify packets, which is what you want.  The main disadvantage is there is no WinXP support.

For an example of redirecting traffic to a proxy server using WinDivert, see [here](http://reqrypt.org/torwall.html).  This transparently redirects web traffic to a proxy server, in this case Privoxy+Tor.  This does so without modifying the web browser's code or configuration in anyway.  That is, the web browsers sees an ordinary Internet connection (albeit somewhat slower thanks to Tor).

Comment: This looks great, I'll play with it. However, it'd be great if there was a way to acomplish that on winxp, so I'll leave the question open :)

Comment: For WinXP you can try WinPkFilter.